# How to create layered PDF with Imagemagick from set of images?

Tags: pdf, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I have set of images like this:
page1_1.png
page1_2.png
page1_3.png
page2_1.png
page2_2.png
page2_3.png

What will I do with Imagemagick to create an output PDF file with 2 pages and 3 layers on each. For example page 1 should be with page1_*.png files and has layers 1-3 that tweaks variations from page1_1 to page1_3. Same with page 2.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: It depends what is in these mysterious layers! If one is the red, one is the blue and one is the green channel the answer will be different from if all layers are basically transparent and contain different objects which don't overlap, or indeed different objects which do overlap - in which case the order will be important.

Comment: Same size, not transparent. I want something like this but in IM:
https://www.pdfill.com/pdf_layer.html
It not depends on color, objects, overlapping, order etc. Just layers like Photoshop on each page.

Comment: I don't believe ImageMagick can do that - and in any case, ImageMagick would delegate that to `ghostscript` so it would depend on `ghostscript` I believe.